Extract values from webpage table using VBA
I need to extract some values from the table in the following website: https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/indicadores/.
I tried to use the solutions given in Extract table from webpage using VBA but neither worked for me.
I am rather new to VBA and I'm not familiar with java. Is there a way to extract only the values 6.869,14 and 0,35. Both are in the last column.
Here is one solution that I was able to find, however it does not seem to be the most efficient or elegant. But it works.
@W_O_L_F solution seems better, but I get an error on objHTTP.send.
Sub scrape_quotes()
   Dim browser As InternetExplorer
   Dim page As HTMLDocument
   
   Set browser = New InternetExplorer
   browser.Visible = False
   browser.navigate ("https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/indicadores/")
   Do While browser.Busy: Loop
   Set page = browser.document
'-----
    Dim spanElement As Object, buttonElement As Object
 
    Set spanElement = page.getElementsByClassName("linhadados")

    aux = spanElement.Length
    
    For i = 0 To spanElement.Length - 1
        If VBA.Left(spanElement.Item(i).innerText, 5) = "IPCA " Then aux_indice = CDbl(VBA.Right(spanElement.Item(i).innerText, 8))
        If VBA.Left(spanElement.Item(i).innerText, 5) = "IPCA1" Then aux_proj = CDbl(VBA.Right(spanElement.Item(i).innerText, 4))
        
    Next i
    browser.Quit
End Sub


If the table always has the same structure, you can access both values directly. However, this is without any protection. If cells can move, this must be taken into account.
Sub ScrapeQuotes()

    Const url As String = "https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/indicadores/"
    Dim doc As Object
    
    Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        
        If .Status = 200 Then
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            MsgBox doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(29).innerText
            MsgBox doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(34).innerText
        Else
            MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Initially, I thought you wanted to scrape the whole table, but when I went through the description again, I could notice that you were after the two values. However, this should do it:
Sub GrabInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/indicadores/"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, WS As Worksheet
    Dim oHttp As Object, N&

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        With Html.querySelectorAll("td")
            For N = 0 To .Length - 1
                If InStr(.Item(N).innerText, "IPCA (mar/24)6") > 0 Then
                    WS.Cells(1, 1) = .Item(N + 2).innerText
                ElseIf InStr(.Item(N).innerText, "IPCA1") > 0 Then
                    WS.Cells(1, 2) = .Item(N + 2).innerText
                End If
            Next N
        End With
    End With
End Sub


I had already heard of xhr. But I understood it a few years ago thanks to a post from you here on SO. Thanks for that.

Maybe this can get you started:
Sub ScrapeWebsite()
'Declare variables
Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim htmlDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim htmlElement As IHTMLElement

Dim url As String
Dim readNextCell As Boolean
Dim IPCA As Boolean
Dim rowSpan As Integer

readNextCell = False
IPCA = False
rowSpan = 0
'Set the URL to be scraped
url = "https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/indicadores/"
'Make a request to the URL
objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
objHTTP.send
'Parse the HTML response
htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = objHTTP.responseText
'Loop through the HTML elements and extract data


For Each aRow In htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("linhadados") '.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'Do something with the data, e.g. print it to the Immediate window
    For Each acell In aRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
    If readNextCell Then
        MsgBox acell.innerText
        readNextCell = False
    End If
    If IPCA And (acell.innerText = "Número Índice" Or acell.innerText = "Projeção (abr/24)") Then
        readNextCell = True
        IPCA = False
    End If
    If (acell.innerText = "IPCA (mar/24)6" Or acell.innerText = "IPCA1") Then
        IPCA = True
        rowSpan = acell.rowSpan
    End If
    Next acell
Next aRow
End Sub

You also need to go to tools/references
and add


I get an error on objHTTP.send: connection interrupted

@Osvaldo Assunção I updated my post you probbably need to go to tools/references an add some libraries
